# Vector Images in background crashing the application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set a Vector Drawable to my RelativeLayout background. I am setting it in my RecyclerView adapter view.

Here is the code

```
  <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
                android:background="@drawable/triangle_white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"/>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="280dp"
            android:height="40dp"
            android:viewportHeight="20"
            android:viewportWidth="100">

        <path
            android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
            android:pathData="M0 20 L100 0 L100 20 Z"
            />

    </vector>
```

It was displaying as black color so i did following changes to enable vector pre lollipop

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

In my main activity i added

```
static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

on top

But i am still getting crash now as "Error inflating view of type

```
ACRA caught a InflateException for xxxxxxxx
                                                                 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                     at xxxxxx.adapter.MaidsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MaidsAdapter.java:93)
                                                                     at xxxxxxx.adapter.MaidsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MaidsAdapter.java:28)
                                                                     at com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(UltimateViewAdapter.java:193)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6367)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.jav
```

Comment: Pls post the stacktrace

Comment: @pskink the crash started happening as soon as i added vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true before that i was getting a black view. If i remove it , it works fine

Comment: so whats the full stacktrace then?

Comment: @JohnnyAW just added error

Comment: @pskink dont think so, just added entire error

Comment: @pskink it displays fine tho without error on preview

Comment: @pskink Nothing more to display in stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define one drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_triangle_white" />
 </selector>
```

and use this file drawable as background

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the support library for `VectorDrawable`, you should use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` in your XML. This might be the reason it is not able to inflate that `view`.

Source - [Android Docs](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)